# Open Source .NET Rich Text Editor UserControl with GUI all implemented

Tags: .net, rich-text-editor

I am writing a data entry program where the last field is going to be a RichTextBox for the user to enter remarks, formatted for print.

Is there a free or opensource .NET WinForms Rich Text Editor with all the GUI already implemented? Most searches end up with web based editors like FCKEditor and friends (or competitors, depending on how you see it).

I am totally going to start a new open source RichTextEditor if there isn't any (I highly doubt).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's [one for WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf-richtexteditor.aspx). And [another one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/WPFRichTextEditor.aspx). And yet [another one](http://wpfricheditorlibrary.codeplex.com/). And here's [one for WinForms](http://yarte.codeplex.com/). So just pick any.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention it is for Winforms. I have found several WPF ones before.

Comment: I just checked YARTE out. it's potentially a great tool.. but why does it have to output as HTML?! =( I need a real RTF editor.

Comment: @Jake, there are also some commercial text editors available. You may take a look at this one: http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Rich_Editor/

Comment: Thanks to your response (+1), I learnt to google for "RTE" instead of "Rich Text Editor" and found http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/eRichTextBox.aspx which happens to be useful. Unfortunately it's not a customizable UserControl, so I am modifying it at the moment... will post a link to my modifed version here in SO as promised, although not sure if it matters or not.

Comment: @Jake - I am looking forward to seeing your UserControl version of that app from Code Project!  Or maybe you can't post is as an answer because the question is closed?  Is it available anywhere?

Comment: link changed for the [one for Winforms](https://github.com/peterhumbert/YARTE)