# WinForms: how to scroll graphics and text continuously to a debugging console?

Tags: winforms

I'd like to scroll a mixture of text and pictures out to a debugging console written in WinForms.

For example, I might print a few lines of text, followed by a graph, followed by more lines of text, etc.

Is there some form of text box in WinForms that I can continuously append not only text, but also pictures or graphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider a Rich Text Edit control.  Here is a question whose answer links to some options.  The question is old, so you may want to re-Google.

[Open Source .NET Rich Text Editor UserControl with GUI all implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978531/open-source-net-rich-text-editor-usercontrol-with-gui-all-implemented)