# Rich Text Editor for winform

Tags: c#, winforms, rich-text-editor

I need a editor which have below thing for a winform app.

[image]

Is there any like this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several Rich Text Editor for winforms, but effective richtext editors are not free.

**Commercial:**
Its handy [Rich Text Editor for WinForms Trial](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b6047f69-08a9-4a56-bd3c-6e0ff758f3fd)

Exactly what you want isw here in Telerik, but its Costly.
[Telerik RichText](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/richtexteditor.aspx)

Here is another [Telerik Control](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/richtexteditor.html)

**Free or Opensource:**

Here is a **codeproject** link with integration details [rtf editor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37169/WPF-RichText-Editor)

Here is another one from [Codeproject RTE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50139/WPF-RichTextEditor-with-Toolbar)

This is a WPF tool [WPF Rich Editor Library](http://wpfricheditorlibrary.codeplex.com/)

And you can look at this [Open Source .NET Rich Text Editor UserControl with GUI all implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978531/open-source-net-rich-text-editor-usercontrol-with-gui-all-implemented)